# Как передать данные в сессию без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Вот появилась такая проблема:
Имеется ссылка вида: domen.ru/index.php?id=7&amp;log=5
При нажатии на ссылку данные id и log записываются в сессию.
Так вот, как это можно реализовать без перезагрузки страницы? Понимаю, что нужно использовать JQuery, js, но не знаю, как, гугл обидел.

Comment: @Шамиль Кадимагомедов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Надо использовать ajax. У тебя должен быть создан документ php, на который ты с помощью ajax отправишь данные, и этот файл php их запишет в сессию.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример: http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/ajax/126-otpravka_soobwenij_pri_pomowi_ajax.html
Делайте на основе его.